# xCode: Error Uploading App

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, app-store-connect, app-distribution

I'm trying to upload my app to itunesconnect using my xCode but I'm stuck with 2 Errors "The port of Signiant is unknown" and "ERROR ITMS-90096" (It says my binary is not optimized for iPhone 5, and is telling about Launch Images). All my Launch Images are working well in all devices, I don't know what's wrong.

Please see the image below:
[image]

Comment: how do you uploading app? Using Organiser or application Loader?

Comment: @JigarTarsariya I'm uploading using Organizer.

Comment: people are facing same issue here - https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50078

Comment: try to reboot everything & upload a fresh build ..may work